# Sending sms from PC using iphone

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, sms

I want to be able to send an SMS from my program to a specified mobile number, in C# .NET. I've seen the related questions, but I'm not familiar with this at all. A few more questions:

1. Can an iphone (unlocked) be used instead of a GSM modem? I know the old Nokia phones can be used for this purpose but i don't have one.
2. Is subscribing to SMS gateway a better/cheaper option?
3. If i purchase a modem, Which would be the best library to use (easy to use). [GSMComm](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm#gsmcomm)?

Comment: Grubbiz if you have found such solution. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ive done this last year. Maybe it do not answers your question but i was using a modem inside my netbook to sent sms. In C# using Gsmcomm. The programm requests every 30 seconds a database where the sms were stored. I created a website where you can post your sms. They were stored in database and the programm on netbook sent it. I used my iphone to post a sms on the website. Works well. If its helpful for you, maybe i get some code.

Comment: Thanks. I think what i'm doing is much simpler. I input the phone number and the program sends a string as a text message to that number. But yeah ultimately I may have to buy a modem after all.

Comment: But where is the part of iphone? Thought you want to sent sms via pc, even if you are not in front of it. That was my idea and the reason why i created the website. If you just want to sent sms via pc i guess you right with buying modem

Comment: I wanted to know if it was possible to use an iPhone as a GSM modem. And yes, I need to prompt the PC whenever I want to send an SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out HappyFingers iphone app.  You can send sms from your windows pc using your iphone.  Dial from your desktop.  Search & select from your iphone contacts on your pc.  www.happyfingersapp.com